# RESTEASY003940: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader [RestEasy 4.5.0.Final]

Tags: java, eclipse, resteasy, tomcat9

My dev stack : 
OpenJDK12, Eclipse december 2019, Tomcat 9.0.31.

I updating my webservice from RestEasy 4.4.1.Final to 4.5.0.Final in my pom.xml and now i have an error

> RESTEASY003940: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader

in bootstrap application.

I have no problem in 4.4.1.Final version.

I created a new empty project in eclipse. I test with OracleJDK1.8 and OpenJDK12, Tomcat 9.0.31 with only RestEasy 4.5.0.Final and i have the same problem.
No problem in 4.4.1.Final version.

An idea ?

Thank you.

**Edit**

The stacktrace :

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003940: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.RegisterBuiltin.register(RegisterBuiltin.java:78)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.startInternal(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.start(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:117)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4533)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5172)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003940: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.CommonProviders.processProviderContracts(CommonProviders.java:93)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ClientHelper.processProviderContracts(ClientHelper.java:104)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.processProviderContracts(ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.java:840)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.java:828)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.java:815)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.RegisterBuiltin.registerProviders(RegisterBuiltin.java:109)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.RegisterBuiltin.register(RegisterBuiltin.java:74)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider()
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.constructOutsideRequest(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:245)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:205)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.Utils.createProviderInstance(Utils.java:102)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.CommonProviders.processProviderContracts(CommonProviders.java:87)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import org.jboss.resteasy.core.messagebody.AsyncBufferedMessageBodyWriter cannot be resolved
    AsyncBufferedMessageBodyWriter cannot be resolved to a type

    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider.<init>(ResteasyJackson2Provider.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.constructOutsideRequest(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:220)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: What messagebodyreader? what's cause? share stacktrace

Comment: Thank you… I forgot the stacktrace. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normally fixed in version 4.5.1.Final.

**Edit :**

Issue Jira for this bug : https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RESTEASY-2507

Comment: Do you have any reference for this claim? Bug report?

Comment: I had the issue Jira.